# Collected company + Eternal witness

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I cast [Collected Company](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCollected%20Company%5d) and one of the creature cards I choose to put into the battlefield is [Eternal Witness](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEternal%20Witness%5d).

By the time Eternal witness enters the battlefield, will Collected company be already in the graveyard so I can put it back to my hand?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can add Collected Company to your hand.

It works like this:

- Collected Company resolves choosing Eternal Witness
- Eternal Witness is put onto the battlefield and triggers (but is not put on the stack yet)
- Collected Company finishes resolving and is put into the graveyard as the last action of casting a spell
- State based actions are checked and see that Eternal Witness has triggered and it's ability is put onto the stack and targets are chosen

By the time Eternal Witness' ability is on the stack and it's time to choose targets, Collected Company is in the graveyard and can be chosen to be returned to hand

Answer (score 2):

Yes you would be able to return Collected Company.  When you place Eternal Witness on the battlefield, the ETB trigger is waiting to go on the stack since the spell is still resolving.  When it's finished and in the graveyard, then you put the trigger on the stack and can legally target the spell.